# Push Rejected when deploying to Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment

I am trying to push my react-app to Heroku but I keep getting this error.[My console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zanwb.png)

I have tried deleting and adding my package.json but it is still not working. Here is my package.json[Package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Acstr.png)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to run `npm run build` locally and see if the build is running successfully?

Seems as though the `react-scripts build` is failing on heroku.

Comment: I ran that and it said build failed, I ended up just making a new repo and copying the files into that repo and it worked when i pushed. Thanks for the guidance!

Comment: Awesome good to hear. I see that it could have been some issue with the branch